# Efficient caching strategy for DB entities with lookup by two fields

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, caching

I have implemented a very simple lookup-cache in order to optimize processing of some DB entities.  The cache class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SyncEngine.Caches
{
    class TenantsCache : Cache
    {
       System.Collections.Generic.List<tenant> list;

        public override void ReadFromDB()
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                this.list = ctx.tenants.ToList<tenant>();
            }
        }

        public override void Add(object o)
        {
            list.Add((tenant)o);
        }

        public tenant LookupByFNandGID(string fn, int groupId)
        {
            tenant match = null;
            foreach (tenant t in list)
            {
                if (t.friendlyName == fn && t.groupId == groupId) // <-- slowest line
                {
                    match = t;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return match;
        }
    }
}
```

By analyzing CPU usage, I see that this Lookup (specifically the highlit line ) takes the most amount of processing time.

Is there a better, significantly more efficient way to implement this lookup/cache and/or the comparison here?  Is there a more efficient in-built Collection with optimized lookup by two fields?

Comment: If you want to solve this on the DB level (you should), Distributed Databases are the droid you are looking for. Many in-process DB's can act as local caching DB in cases that performance maters or for cases when the connection to the main DB is unreliable (mobile Applications). For SQL, it would be SQL Express. However as you question deals with speed, I feel compelled to link the speed rant: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ Particulary Parts 2 and 4 mater for your case.

Comment: thanks, but yes I really need to answer that question, and I won't know whether the difference is relevant until I have something to compare to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Dictionary with a custom key that contains both fields:

```
class Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    public string fn;
    public int groupId;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Key k = obj as Key;
        if (k == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Equals(k);
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Key other)
    {
        return this.fn == other.fn && this.groupId == other.groupId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return fn.GetHashCode() * 13 + groupId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use a dictionary which is much faster for lookup than a list:

```
Dictionary<Key, tenant> foo = new Dictionary<Key, tenant>();
```

Comment: given that the implementation of `Equals` is the same as the comparison I was already doing, will the Dictionary lookup really be much more efficient?

Comment: The dictionary request will be executed after O(1), meanwhile foreach - O(N).

Comment: The dictionary first uses GetHashCode to find a bucket in an internal hash table it keeps. Once it has narrowed down to a bucket, it uses Equals within the bucket to find the entry you are looking for. This means that even for dictionaries with millions of items, it only calls Equals a couple times.